# Возобновление передачи файлов по локальной сети , при разрыве связи

Tags: c#, загрузка, share

Есть программа,без серверной части.Которая авторизуется через шару \ip\c$... логин, пасс, и передает файлы из папки C:\papka  в  \ip\c$...,но иногда случается обрыв связи.Как возобновлять передачу этого же файла? Файл Т1 весит 10 мб. Бывают разрывы свази,нужно Т1 докачать с c:\papka\ до \127.0.0.1\c$\papka\ ,даже если будет потеря связи в моменте передачи из папки в папку,нужно чтобы возобновлял передачу,а не обрывал её совсем,как сейчас.

```
NetworkShare.DisconnectFromShare(@"\\127.0.0.1\c$\papka", true); //Remove this line
NetworkShare.ConnectToShare(@"\\127.0.0.1\c$\papka", "user1", "password1!"); //Connect with the new credentials

File.Copy(@"c:\papka\T1.txt", @"\\127.0.0.1\c$\papka\T1.txt");

NetworkShare.DisconnectFromShare(@"\\127.0.0.1\c$\papka", false); //Remove this line also

NetworkShare.DisconnectFromShare(@"\\127.0.0.1\c$\papka", false); //Remove this line also
```

Comment: Код в студию...

Comment: @aepot Добавил код,постарался подробнее описать